# Is there an easy way to Spellcheck with TinyMCE in .NET

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, spell-checking

Is there any way to use TinyMCE in .NET and use the spellchecker without installing PHP as well?

Comment: I know this is a few years old. Wondering if anyone has come up with any newer solutions. Seems that Google's Soap Search API is deprecated so that solution won't work.

I have a .NET (MVC) application that uses TinyMCE as the text editor. Would like to implement a .NET plugin solution besides the default PHP one.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [Netspell](http://www.loresoft.com/Applications/NetSpell/default.aspx) spellchecker for .NET.  We use it in conjunction with TinyMCE.  It works well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are several possibilities to spellcheck using tinymce:

- spellcheck plugin (you are able to specify which external webadress should check the spelling (i.e. google spellcheck))
- firefox spellchecker (you need to activate the configuration settings "gecko_spellcheck: true,")
- Spellcatcher (an OS based software to spellcheck even in the browser, but there are programs like this)

Answer (score 0):

I also use this http://www.spellchecker.net/v3/editors/tinymce.html TnyMCE Plugin hope helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want the browsers internal spellchecker, I got it working by removing the "contextmenu" plugin from tinymce:init plugin section.

I use Chrome and also had to add the following inside tinymce:init to enable Chromes internal spellchecker.

gecko_spellcheck : true

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `browser_spellcheck: true` in the options.

**e.g.**

```
tinymce.init({
    browser_spellcheck: true
});
```

Note: I think was is as-of TinyMCE 4, but it works with most modern browsers.